# Limit that is able to count a square root.

Tags: limits, algorithms, radicals, recursive-algorithms

Can anyone explain me why does that limit is actually solving square root :

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{x}_{n} = \sqrt{a} \\{x}_{0} = \frac{a}{2}; \quad {x}_{n} = 0.5*({x}_{n-1} + \frac{a}{{x}_{n-1}}); \\n = 1, 2, ...$

I was not able to find anything else except binary search for square root problem, so I have no idea how the limit will turn out to be the right answer.

Comment: you must include the text in Dollar signs

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, are you an actual Graubner? The one that studied polynomials profoundly?

Comment: The recurrence can be rewritten as $x_{n} = x_{n-1} - \frac{x_{n-1}^2 - a }{2x_{n-1}}$. Now compare it with [Newton Raphson's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) of finding root of a function $f(x)$: $x_{n} = x_{n-1} - \frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}$

Comment: yes i'm Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, it is very cool. Glad to see you.

Comment: ok i'm glad too

Comment: This recurrence does not work. Should it be $x_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}})$?

Comment: @CYAries, I took the reccurence from book and there is no division by two. Maybe it is a typo.

Comment: @CYAries, yes I see. Here is a typo in the book.

Comment: @achillehui, pretty good explanation. Thank you for the help. But, maybe there are better explanations? Because I do not know why Newton`s method works.

Comment: use the AM-GM inequality

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, can you explain it more specific, please? I do not get the idea.

Comment: This iterative method for approximating square roots is called the Babylonian Method. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

note that $$\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}\right)\geq \sqrt{a}$$

Comment: Why does that holds? And why for all n > 1 $ {x}_{n} < {x}_{n-1}$? If you explain that it will be really great. I will immediately chose your answer.

Comment: use that $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $$a,b\geq 0$$ and set $$a=x_{n-1},b=\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}$$

Comment: and prove $$x_n<x_{n-1}$$ by induction

Answer (score 2):

Here is the easiest approach I found to get it:

1. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x}_{n}=b$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x}_{n-1}=b$ as well.
2. Now let us notice that the limit actually exists.

Having 1. and 2. we infer that $2b = b + a/b \implies b^2 = a.$

So, the limit really counts square root.